# Validating form dropdown in CodeIgniter

Tags: forms, codeigniter, validation

I am using CodeIgniter's form helper and form validation library to build my forms. I'm having trouble making the dropdown 'sticky' and also finding appropriate validation rules.

This is how I'm populating the drodown:

```
foreach($events as $event){
$options[$event->event_title] = $event->event_title;
}
$firstItem = '<option>Please select one...</option>';
echo form_dropdown('events', $options, '', $firstItem);
```

This is building the options from events stored in the database. The form looks fine and is populating all the fields correctly.

Hwoever, when I come to submit the form, the dropdown isn't holding onto the value selected? Also, how should I validate it, I want to make it required but I also want to make sure that I dont except the first option in the dropdown 'Please select one...'

Thanks in advance.

Cheers,
Gaz

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you doing this in a view? I'll show you have I handle this, but it all happens in a controller:

```
// first, we can set a validation rule for the input 'country' (our dropdown), in this case it is required, and must be a natural number. You can look up more rules in the CI user guide, and you can write your own functions as well and add them to the 3rd parameter here. I believe some native PHP functions can be used as well.
$this->form_validation->set_rules('country', 'Country', 'required|is_natural');

// the form is not valid! we'll enter this block whenever the form validation rules above are not met, as well as when first going to this controller-action.
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
    // buid your form, there's some CI functions to help with this that I'm using
    $my_form = form_open('user/edit', 'class="superform"')
        . form_fieldset()
        . '<ol>'
        . '<li>'
        . form_label('Country<br/>', 'country')
        // so here is the dropdown, matching the name given to the validation rule we've set, the second parameter takes an array, which I am grabbing from a model, the last parameter is the 'selected; value, which I am grabbing from some variable, if it's not present the first item in the dropdown will obviously be selected
        . form_dropdown('country', $this->Country_model->get_countries_dropdown(), $user->country)
 . form_error('country', ' <em>', '</em>'
        . form_submit('mysubmit', 'Save', 'class="button"')
        . '</li>'
        . '</ol>'
        . form_fieldset_close()
        . form_close()
    );
    // sending the form variable to my view, where i will simply <?=$my_form?> it
    $this->load->view('user_edit', $my_form);
} else {
    // form has validated! do something!
}
```

The form_dropdown() function takes an array that is setup like:
    $key => $value
Where the key in my case is a country id, and the value is the countries name. I have the pair '0' => 'NONE' at the start of my country array, so the user cannot choose one. If i wanted to make this required like your situation, I could set it to '-1' => 'Please select...' and it would not validate, as -1 is not a natural number.

Hope my rambling helps!

Edit:

Okay, so before you create the dropdown with form_dropdown(), what you'll want to do is check for a selected value from coming from the POST array.

In the case of CI, you can use the function set_value($input), so in my example form I might do something like:

```
$selected = (!empty(set_value('country'))) ? set_value($country) : '';

form_dropdown('country', $this->Country_model->get_countries_dropdown(), $selected)
```

So now the selected value of the dropdown will be set to what was selected on the last post. You might want to check that value to make sure it's valid. If nothing was selected, then you could set $selected as something like the value currently in the database, or a default value you've chosen.

Comment: That's great - that worked fine. You would think there would be a better way of doing it though? Also, any ideas how you make the dropdown 'sticky'?

Comment: Do you mean like, if the form was submitted but something else didn't validate, and you want the dropdown to have the same selected value?

Comment: Yeh, that's what I mean.

Re: validation - CI seems to have good documentation for basic input validation but not so much for dropdowns. Also, I would have thought there would be a high percentage of dropdowns that are populated from database values and so set_select() would cater for it, seems not?

Comment: I've added more to my answer in case you missed it. Basically what I do it check if there is a valid POST value to set, if not, something pulled from the database, otherwise set a default.

Answer (score 4):

In you line:

```
echo form_dropdown('events', $options, '', $firstItem);
```

Just make it:

```
echo form_dropdown('events', $options, set_value('events'), $firstItem);
```

Comment: Important: for set_value() to work when the form validation library is used, the field ('events' in this example) must be part of the validation rules.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I REALLY like building my form in the view rather than mixing the presentation into the controller. But that's just my opinion. I understand having to pre-load data if it's a large list but I don't think you really need to build the entire form just for a drop down list. I had the same issue and actually did a little doc digging to figure out a good solution.

**To Validate the Selection Choices**
All I did for that was provide a custom method in the controller class that looks something like this

```
function select_validate($selectValue)
{
    // 'none' is the first option and the text says something like "-Choose one-"
    if($selectValue == 'none')
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('select_validate', 'Please pick one.');
        return false;
    }
    else // user picked something
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

In your index() (or whichever method is processing the data and loading the view) you set your validation code for the drop down.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('select', 'Select', 'callback_select_validate');
```

It's **imperative** that you prefix your custom function with "callback_".

**Maintaining User Selection**
Retaining the selection choices is super simple too if you use what CI gives you. You just need to use the set_select() function for each option in the selection list.

So let's say you have a drop down with two options to make it easy. This is all you do.

```
<select name="select">
    <option value="none" <?php echo set_select('select', 'none', true);?> >- Select One -</option>
    <option value="one" <?php echo set_select('select', 'one');?> >Option one</option>
    <option value="two" <?php echo set_select('select', 'two');?> >Option two</option>
</select>
```

What's nice about using this function is that it pre-selects the first "dummy" option and then if the user makes a selection but fails other validations, the selection will be retained and pre-selected after the form is posted and prompts the user to correct the other errors.

Again, this may not satisfy everyone but it's a pretty straight forward solution for drop down validation with CodeIgniter.

Comment: Agreed. Much more of a fan of working with my html in plain site. Sometimes helpers can limit experimentation and code neatness.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem as well, after reading the recommended post here, i got it working but I was annoyed because of the validation message it returns. However I believe I have found a better option:

```
foreach($events as $event){
    $options[$event->event_title] = $event->event_title;
}

$firstItem[''] = 'Please select one...';

// I used array merge to ensure that my firstItem was infact my first item, 
// otherwise you could just do $options[''] = 'Please select one...'. 
// Array_unshift also does not allow you to specify the [''] array key we want
$options = array_merge($firstItem, $options);

$selected_option = $this->input->post('events', TRUE) ? $this->EE->input->post('events', TRUE) : '';

echo form_dropdown('events', $options, $selected_option);
```

Then with the validation you can simply do:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('events', 'Events', 'required');
```

Then the validation returns the normal 'required' message

Comment: Hurray! The trick here is to set the array key to an empty string, so that value validates as empty.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and managed to solve it:

- javascript validation using spry validation javascript
- codeigniter callback function in form validation class

If you may need specific code i can help out