# Validating country dropdown form

Tags: codeigniter, validation, drop-down-menu

First of all, I have already readed this: [Validating form dropdown in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442255/validating-form-dropdown-in-codeigniter)

But it doesnt solve my problem:

As you know, `<option>` value can be faked for example using firebug.

My select options looks like this:

```
<option value="ger">Germany</option>
<option value="uk">United Kingdom</option>
<option value="usa">United States of America</option>
[...]
```

Now, how can I validate if the choosen and posted value is correct?
These values are builded on the large array. It looks following:

```
$countries = array (
     'ger' => 'Germany',
     'uk'  => 'United Kingdom',
     'usa' => 'United States of America'
);
```

So how can I validate, of choosen value is correct? Will I have to use the `array_key_exist` with function callback on form validation?

What in case if my select options looks like this?

```
<option value="0">Choose Something</option>
<option value="1">Select-1</option>
<option value="2">Select-2</option>
[..]
```

How can I validate the above using the form validator, so I could check if the posted value is correct and not faked, also how to prevent from choosing the `0` value?

The best idea for this in my opinion is creating the function callback, which will look following:

```
public function validate_values($input)
{
      $allowed = array(1, 2, 3, 4); //[..]
      if ( !in_array( $input, $allowed ) )
      {
           //throw error, and do the rest...
      }

}
```

Are my ideas "ok" or there are any better solutions for these cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback is exactly what you need. I think that's why they were created. In user guide:

> "The validation system supports callbacks to your own validation
>   functions. This permits you to extend the validation class to meet
>   your needs."

So if your need is to check if submitted values are from defined range, use it. 
Of course it should return false or true depending on result. [user guide for callbacks](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks)
For me it's the best solution. Especially because you need to check those values after form is submitted.

As for preventing from choosing 0, don't put 0 to `in_array` or check first if `$input` is `!empty` for example and set correct error message. If you're creating your own callback you can validate that `$input` for whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks. Thats enough informations for me :). Regarding preventing from choosing `0`: I've used the `is_natural_no_zero` rule to prevent from choosing `0` and then I just set my own message :).

Comment: Yep, is_natural_no_zero is great choice for that. :o)