# how to modify <select required> to form_dropdown in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

according to the question asked by Outliers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28162771/codeigniter-dropdown-validation-set-rules/28166382#28166382), and according to the answer posted by Adr

```
echo form_dropdown('salutation', $salutationOptions, '', 'required="required"');
```

i've tried similar line of code when creating form_dropdown in controller of code igniter, i do it like this

```
$code = array(
   'type'   => 'text',
   'id'     => 'productcode',
   'name'   => 'productcode',
   'class'  => 'form-control',
   'required'=> 'required'
);

$form['open'] = form_open_multipart('Mould/saveeditproduct');
$form['code'] = form_input($code);
$form['category'] = form_dropdown('category',$category,'','id="category" class="form-control" required="required"');
$form['submit'] = form_input($submit);
$form['close'] = form_close();
```

i try to run the program, i found that the 'required' property is worked well in form_input, but does not work in form_dropdown. so, how can i fix this? thank you

Comment: I just tried echoing out your $form['category'] and it works exactly as expected. What results are you getting?

Comment: thank you for the answer.. actually, i want that if i don't select the category, when i press the submit button it will shows an alert or something like form_input did. but in my case, when i press submit button it will save the form to the DB, and ignore the required property

Comment: You should be using the form_validation library regardless of what attributes you put on your form fields. Making it required through form_validation will stop it being published to the DB. It's really, really simple to use a third-party tool to remove that attribute and let the POST array go through. It's less simple to bypass the form_validation. It can be done, but it's non-trivial for the majority of the population.

Comment: can you show the `$category` array?

Comment: @shihas, i get the $category from this 
    $data['category'] = $this->Mouldmodel->getallcategory();
 $category[] = array();
 $category[0] = '----- Select Category -----';
 foreach($data['category'] as $dm){
  $category[$dm->idcategory] = $dm->categoryname;
 }

Comment: can you `print_r($category)` and check `'----- Select Category -----` is there in first position

Comment: problem is while creating `$category` array. Try the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that you assigned a value for first option in dropdown (`----- Select Category -----`) as **`0`**

Try this code:

```
// $data['category'] = array( array('idcategory' => 4,'categoryname' => 'new'),
//                            array('idcategory' => 2,'categoryname' => 'old'));

$data['category'] = $this->Mouldmodel->getallcategory();
$category[] = array(); 
$category[''] = '----- Select Category -----'; 
foreach($data['category'] as $dm){ 
  $category[$dm['idcategory']] = $dm['categoryname']; 
}
```

Comment: great, yes its work! thank you @Shihas, but can you tell me why its make a different between '$category['']' and '$category[0]'?

currently, i just understand that '$category[]' is an array, and array is started from 0

Comment: The value for `'----- Select Category -----'` should be an empty value inorder to work the validation. In your case you have given value `0` for it. You can see that in inspect element.

Comment: hummm, i see.. so, when i write $category[0] its mean that the array is not empty.. ok thank you @Shihas, i undersatnd it now.. :D

Comment: Welcome. Glad to help you :)